# How can I add vanilla C# code and tests to a Unity project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity (version 2020.2.1f1) project and I've factored out a small utility in C# which I'd like to unit test. Currently in order to compile, the utility class needs to extend `MonoBehaviour`, but I'd like to avoid this and keep the class pure C#.

I've looked for documentation on unit testing in Unity, but can only find the Unity Test Framework which seems to be geared to game code rather than pure C#. Is there a way to unit test vanilla C# code in Unity?

Comment: You can decouple logic from the MB class to a c# class. The MB contains the unity lifecycle meth9ds and editor referencing. It calls the logic passing down needed info. You would unit test the logic in edit mode, no need to test the MB, unity did it for you. Then in play mode you can test the scene logic with all GO since it has the engine running. Abstract all dependencies to interfaces to mock them.

Answer (score 0):

The following article mentions nothing about a testcase having to include Unity-specific code https://www.raywenderlich.com/9454-introduction-to-unity-unit-testing

Unity IS C# after all. Not everything in your project has to use the Unity API

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to implement `MonoBehaviour`?

I would suggest you have e.g.

```
public class YourClass 
{
    ... 
}
```

and where/if at all needed you wrap it in a

```
public class YourClassBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public YourClass yourClassInstance; 
}
```

And then only test the internal functionality of the `YourClass`.

---

Either way: **It doesn't need to be anything Unity specific in order to unit test it**.

You can just go ahead and e.g. do

```
namespace YourThingy.EditorTests
{
    public class YourClassTest
    {
        private YourClass yourClassInstance;

        [OneTimeSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            yourClassInstance = new YourClass();
        }

        [Test]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            yourClassInstance.DoSomething();
            Assert.AreEuqual("someValue", yourClassInstance.someValue);
        }

        [Test]
        public void SoemTestThatIsntEvenUsingYourClass()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(1f == (2f * 5f / 10f));
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can see the Unit test are pure c# and don't necessarily use anything from the Unity API (except of course the test framework itself)

In order to not have to enter play mode just make sure you are using `Editor Tests`.